Why can forces be split into components?
Is there some physical understanding to it or we just know that nature works that way?
I used to think of it as was that if a force acts on an object in a certain direction producing some acceleration then it will be displaced in that direction by some amount $d$ then it's displacement in horizontal direction assuming angle with it to be $\theta$ will be $d\cos\theta$ by trigonometry and corresponding acceleration will be $a\cos\theta$. now if we were to think of it as a force acting in the X direction it will have magnitude $ma\cos\theta$ and since $ma$ is magnitude of initial force we can write $ma\cos\theta$ as $F\cos\theta$.
That means it's a way in which we defined a force from the quantities displacement/acceleration that an object has so then why can we say that we are applying a force of $20\text{N}$ (say) and it's component in some direction is $10\text{N}$ even if the object didn't even accelerate in that direction it was constrained to move by a wall or something.
This isn't explained in the answer to a similar question.

A question of this form, you need to know what kind of answers you would accept. It was from the study of forces that the mathematical concept of vectors was created, and in so doing, the physical understanding and mathematical understanding of vector addition and component splitting were figured out. Would you accept that as an answer?

Hmm so you say we figured that out from looking at nature what I used to think of it as was that if a force acts on an object in a certain direction producing some acceleration then it will be displaced in that direction by some amount x then it's displacement in horizontal direction assuming angle with it to be theta will be xcostheta by trigonometry and corresponding acceleration will be acos(theta)now if we were to think of it as a force acting in the X direction it will have magnitude macos(theta) and since ma is magnitude of initial force we can write macos(theta) as Fcos(theta)

(ran out of characters) so that seems like a mathematical trick but it fails when the motion is constrained in a particular direction and we then will have to split the force

This question is similar to: How do we know that force is a vector?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can someone please help in answering the comment or the question in the edit made

This "question" looks like a mixture of two questions: (A) Given some vector $F$, why are we allowed to talk about two other vectors, $G$ and $H$, which do not necessarily have the same direction as $F$, and for which $F=G+H$? Because that's what "split into components" means. What is the meaning of the relationship between $F$ and $G$ and $H$? The second question, (B), seems to be a question about Newton's second law of motion, $F=mA$, but I'm not quite sure that I understand what exactly is the trouble with that one.

Re, "why can we say that we are applying a force...in some direction...
even if the object didn't even accelerate in that direction." If it did not accelerate, then we weren't applying a net force. If you apply a force to a ball sitting on a table top, and if the direction of the force that you apply is not parallel to the table top, and if the ball does not accelerate into or off of the table top, then that means that the vertical component of the force that you applied is cancelled out by some other force (e.g., by the contact force from the table top.) There was no net vertical force.

Hey thanks for replying, ig I've understood it now it's just that since the interactions between objects by forces are similar then the tendency to change the momentum by overcoming the inertia of an object be similar following the law F = dp/dt and then we just use trigonometry and assume two different forces for simplicity/calculation purposes to find how much would be the tendency to accelerate some body in a particular direction by the same magnitude of interaction (which we call a force). So because the way a force works(causes change in momentum which is a vector) itcanalso.be.thoughtas1

If you could please tell if that's correct or pls correct me if I'm wrong somewhere....

All vectorial quantities can be separated into components. Forces have a magnitude and a direction, and are therefore vectors. So it must be possible to write them in terms of components. Of course, the components you choose depend on the coordinate system you wish to use.

Ig we derived the laws that vectors obey based on how physical entities like forces work that's why I wanted a reason...
